# Problema con Wordpress (Warning & Fatal Error) ha desaparecido mi web

Tags: wordpress

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y bueno, ya corregi todos los archivos sobre los permisos, el problema es que solo me aparece esa advertencia, y verificando esa linea, me indica que el problema esta en "Query.php" no se que tan recomendable sea borrarlo.

Necesito ayuda por favor, hago todo por medio de filezilla.

Comment: Te recomendaría que re-instales Wordpress. Si era un sitio que estaba ya funcionando podrás hacer que el nuevo Wordpress apunte a la antigua base de datos una vez instalado, editando el archivo `wp-config.php`

Comment: Disculpa el sitio web aparece, pero solo si cambio los permisos del archivo "Query.php", todo desaparece cuando tiene el permiso 200 y cuando lo cambio al 644, todo vuelve a aparecer, significa que hay algo que esta cambiando los permios de este archivo cada 5 min. Alguna idea de que pueda ser? O como se realiza lo que recomiendas con lo del archivo "wp-config.php"? Gracias por aportar y ayudar

Comment: `query.php` en esa ruta es un archivo propio de Wordpress, si, como dices, hay *algo* que cambia los permisos de ese archivo debes verificar qué es ese *algo* y hacer que no cambie los permisos. El comportamiento que describes no es normal y deberías revisar, pues incluso puede ser algo grave, como que un hacker haya tomado control del servidor, o que haya un programa mal intencionado ejecutándose en el servidor, etc.

Comment: Alguna recomendación para descifrar o encontrar que es lo que esta oacsionando esto? Algun software o elemento que yaude a localizar este tipo de ejecuciones?

Comment: Puedes verificar por ejemplo si tienes plugin instalados en tu Wordpress. Repito que lo mejor para estos casos es instalar Wordpress de nuevo y luego hacer que la instalación apunte a tu antigua base de datos, si era un sitio que ya estaba funcionando. Si es un sitio nuevo, reinstalas todo de nuevo, incluyendo la base de datos. Luego ten cuidado con los plugin, temas y otros. No instales plugin/temas que tengan más de 6 meses sin actualizar, pueden contener bugs y agujeros de seguridad.

Comment: Logré solucionarlo sustituyendo el archivo por uno nuevo, parece que se restableció, muchas gracias!